# How can you override "cmd" of docker for aws lambda in CDK?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I write `CMD ["main.handler"] in Dockerfile`, but I'm trying to change handler function for reusing same container image.
How can you fix my CDK code?
I found [CodeImageConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CodeImageConfig.html) interface, but have no idea how to use this option.

CDK code

```js
const fn = new lambda.Function(scope, `lambda-fn`, {
    code: new lambda.AssetImageCode("./lambda/myapp", {
        ignoreMode: IgnoreMode.DOCKER,
        file: "lambda.Dockerfile",
    }),
    handler: lambda.Handler.FROM_IMAGE,
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
    tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
    environment: {
        SAMPLE_ENV_VAR: "sample_env_var",
    },
});
```

lambda.Dockerfile

```py
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
COPY src/ /var/task/
CMD ["main.handler"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `AssetImageCode`, which has a `cmd` prop. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.AssetImageCodeProps.html#cmd):

```
cmd?

Type: string[] (optional, default: use the CMD specified in the docker image or Dockerfile.)

Specify or override the CMD on the specified Docker image or Dockerfile.

This needs to be in the 'exec form', viz., [ 'executable', 'param1', 'param2' ].
```

```js
...
    code: new lambda.AssetImageCode("./lambda/myapp", {
        ignoreMode: IgnoreMode.DOCKER,
        file: "lambda.Dockerfile",
        cmd: ["entrypoint", "main.handler"],
    }),
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a very concise and nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using CDK v2 with Python and `DockerImageFunction` for a project currently - the accepted answer did **not** work for me.

I am using an AWS managed image in my case - specifically, the [`public.ecr.aws/lambda/python`](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/python) image.

#### Dockerfile

This line is at the top of my `Dockerfile` ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html)):

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
```

> *Note*: I had added the `--platform` to work around local deployments with an M1 Mac in my case.

To be on the safe side, I also specified `AMD64` as the platform in CDK code:

```py
from aws_cdk.aws_ecr_assets import Platform

# needed for Mac M1 deployments
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
platform: Platform = Platform.LINUX_AMD64

function = lambda_.DockerImageFunction(
    self, 'MyFunction',
    code=lambda_.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
        str(work_dir),
        platform=platform,
        cmd=...,
    ),
)
```

#### CDK - Attempt #1

In my CDK code, the suggested syntax did *not* work for me.

```py
cmd=['entrypoint', 'main.handler']
```

Error from CloudWatch logs:

```
entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 142 Runtime.ExitError
```

#### CDK - Attempt #2

I also tried the following, after consulting from the official [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/blob/python3.9/Dockerfile.python3.9#L18) for the image:

```py
cmd=['/lambda-entrypoint.sh', 'main.handler']
```

The same error was observed from the CloudWatch logs when attempting to run the affected AWS Lambda function.

#### CDK - Attempt #3

What **did** work, was just passing in `cmd` with the handler as the first argument, as I originally had in [my `Dockerfile`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-create):

```py
cmd=['main.handler']
```

> *Tip*: Use the dot `.` syntax all throughout. For example, if you have a directory called `app` under `$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` (`/var/task`) and within that a `handlers.py` file with a function `my_handler`, the following syntax will work:
>
> ```py
> cmd=['app.handlers.my_handler']
> ```

All works fine now. Everything is good :-)